# How to crop image in linux

Tags: linux

Ok I know about the convert tool and I am wondering can it be used to say just remove the bottom 50 pixels in an image leaving the rest of the image intact.

Can it be done in batch?

Lets say i have 20 images of various sizes and want to remove just the bottom 50 pixels for example the image is of size 800x600 so the new image would be 750x600

If convert cant do this is there anything for linux that can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that you cannot do this with convert.

Take a look here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop

Here is a script which creates thumbnails and identifies the width and height of the original image:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Define a fixed resolution
long=500
short=600
# Creating thumbnails
(for i in *.png *.jpg; do
width=`identify -format %w $i`
height=`identify -format %h $i`
if [ $width -ge $height ]; then
  size=${long}x
else
  size=x${short}
fi

echo "# Resizing $i $width""x""$height -> $size" ;

convert -resize $size -quality 80 -gravity center -extent $size -background white $i /media/path/to/destination
done
)
```

You can modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: So im getting 'convert image: -crop lxw+x+y  crop.gif' so how do i tell it to use w as the width of the original image and for l to be 50 less than the original image and to start from the top left corer?

Comment: You should be able to get the width of your original image in this way: 'identify -format "%f,%w,%h"'. The variable w should contain the width. I can post a script later today (have it at home) which might help you.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated. I have tons of images that were sent to me by a friend. and they have timestamps on the bottom corner of each one. He wants me to crop the bottom 50 pixels or so to remove the time/date stamps and then send them back to him so he can have them printed. They are mostly family photos.

Comment: Have you had a chance yet?

Comment: First of all, sorry for not answering any sooner, but the question was migrated so I had to talk to the moderators to get this profiles connected so that the answer was recognized as mine (otherwise I cannot comment with no rep). I'll add the script to the answer.

Comment: I actually ended up finding out about -chop